# Blender boolean difference not working as expected

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

When a apply a boolean modify to my terrain mesh it is not applying it correctly.

Here is my terrain

[image]

Here is the water I would like to cut out.

[image]

but when I cut it out, I get the following

[image]

I anticipated that it would remove the water line from the landscape, but it appears to not be doing what I expected. Instead of performing the operation I would expect, it's executing a bizarre kind of boolean operation that exclusively trims the terrain encircled by water.

Comment: Judging by the artifacts on the mesh in your first image I don't think your terrain mesh is manifold which doesn't bode well with the boolean modifier